# Information on Flutter Bloc pattern to reuse the state and event classes

Tags: flutter, bloc, concept, equatable

I am using `flutter_bloc` package for state management and extends with `Equatable`. I have made `Event class` and `state class` for the data to display which I receive from `api`. It is the simple app where I am receiving data from `api` and just to display on the screen on `UI`. Everything works good. But now I also want to check the internet connectivity and display the snackBar if internet is not working. For this I will use `Connectivity_plus` package of flutter. But as I am using the `Bloc pattern` I already have one `state class` and one `event` class.

My question is, if now I would like to have the feature if Internet is working or not and if I want to implement in `Bloc pattern` then I have to create new `NetworkState class` and `NetworkEvent class`? OR I can reuse the `state` and `event` class which I already have in my app ??

In the general terms every time we have to make new `states class` and `event class` for the new feature or we can reuse these class for every feature which we implement in `Bloc pattern` in flutter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice is you should make separate state and event classes for each feature in your app. This can help keep the code organized and makes it easier to maintain and expand your application in the future.
for example, in your situation, you can create a new NetworkEvent class that will fire when the application detects a change in network connectivity and a new NetworkState class that will contain the current network connection state. This way, you can keep your existing state and event classes focused on your application's existing functionality, and add new capabilities to networking functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and clearing the subject.

Answer (score 2):

As Dewa suggested, you should probably create a new bloc (along with new events and states) for the connectivity feature.

Bloc's design tends to encourage keeping a bloc/cubit simple and have only one responsibility.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the other answers, just one thing to note. `connectivity_plus` doesn't verify whether the device has connectivity or not, just whether its on wifi or mobile data etc...To confirm the ability to connect online, [internet_connection_checker](https://pub.dev/packages/internet_connection_checker) is the better tool.

You can manually check, or subscribe to its stream of `InternetConnectionStatus`  and always be up to date. Just call the `NetworkInitConnectionListener` on app start and you're good to go.

`emit.forEach` is an easy way to subscribe to a stream in Bloc and return a new state on each new stream update. If you don't need/want an updated state, just return `state`;

```
import 'package:internet_connection_checker/internet_connection_checker.dart';

class NetworkBloc extends Bloc<NetworkEvent, InternetConnectionStatus> {
  NetworkBloc() : super(InternetConnectionStatus.connected) {
    on<NetworkInitConnectionListener>(_onNetworkInitConnectionListener);
  }

  Future<void> _onNetworkInitConnectionListener(
    NetworkInitConnectionListener event,
    Emitter<InternetConnectionStatus> emit,
  ) async {
    final connectionStream = InternetConnectionChecker().onStatusChange;

    // Will emit a new state whenever the stream is updated
    emit.forEach(
      connectionStream,
      onData: (InternetConnectionStatus status) => status,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard approach, just go with what suits you. I prefer having base state and event classes for simple blocs or cubits.

State classes:

```
abstract class BaseState extends Equatable {
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [];
}

class InitialState extends BaseState {}

class LoadingState extends BaseState {}

class SuccessState extends BaseState {}

class ErrorState extends BaseState {
  ErrorState({required this.error});
  final Err error;
}
```

Event classes:

```
abstract class BaseEvent {}

class LoadDataEvent extends BaseEvent {}

class RefreshDataEvent extends BaseEvent {}

class RetryEvent extends BaseEvent {}
```

And the bloc would look like:

```
class MyBloc extends BaseBloc<BaseEvent, BaseState> {}
```